# I have to, I'd have to

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "I have to" and "I'd have to"?

> Who do you care about most?
> I'd have to say my mom.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

“I have to say my mom.” seems equivalent to
“I must say my mom.”,
implying that I have no choice; there is no other answer I can make. It is imperative to choose my mom.

“I would have to say my mom” cannot be changed to use “must”. The imperative force is no longer present. Instead, the use of “would” makes the choice conditional.

But conditional on what? I suggest the construct implies that the speaker is admitting that even **if** they think of other possibilities (sisters, brothers, friends etc), they would chose mom.

Comment: Looking at the meanings of [would](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603046/i-have-to-id-have-to), it could express a preference or mean doubt or uncertainty, but in this sense it could have a habitual meaning - whenever I'm asked this, I say it is my mother.

Comment: @StuartF fair point. I actually believe that the question was inappropriately closed. It is not trivial, not easy for a non- native speaker to deal with from reference sources, and deserves more attention, particularly when posed by a newcomer to the site, who should be encouraged, not dismissed. I shall flag for reopening.

Comment: _If I had to make a choice, (I guess) I'd have to choose X_ is close to what it's short for. That's a very personal question to ask, and any answer is likely to be very tentative. Stating it this way showcases the uncertainty of the response.